# How do I initialise the plot of my function to start at 0?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, random-walk

This is probably a really stupid question, but I just can't seem to work out how to do it for some reason. I've created a function for a random walk here which just uses the numpy binomial function with one trial (ie if it's under 0.5 it's -1, over it's +1. However this obviously makes the first value of the function either -1 or +1, whereas I want it to be zero. How can I change this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_walk(N,d):
    walk = d*np.cumsum(2*np.random.binomial(1,.5,N-1)-1)
    return walk

plt.plot(np.arange(1,250),random_walk(250,1))
plt.show()
```

Again, it's probably really simple and I'm being really stupid, but I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: `np.arange(0,249)` instead of `np.arange(1,250)`, the first parameter of the function `plot` is the axis.

Comment: I mean the y-axis though, not the x-axis. This just makes the coordinate (0,-1) or (0,1), I want it to be (0,0). I realise I need to change it to np,arange(0,250) for that to work but I'm not sure how to set the initial value of the function.

Comment: sorry, I misread, I posted an answer with a little modification in your code. I hope this is what you wanted. You should just start your distribution at zero, because it's your starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little tweak to your code. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def random_walk(N,d):
    walk = np.concatenate(([0],np.cumsum(2*np.random.binomial(1,.5,N-1)-1)))
    return walk

plt.plot(np.arange(0,250),random_walk(250,1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Be carefull on how you plot, you can plot just with `plt.plot(random_walk(250,1))` since you don't care about the x axis.